# angularjs first value select in dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I want to select option if option have only one

```
<select class="perf-select" 
    ng-model="viewProfileCtrl.monthsForm.institution"
    ng-options="inst.institution.institution_id as inst.institution.name for inst in viewProfileCtrl.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions"
    ng-change="viewProfileCtrl.setCurrMonthInsti(viewProfileCtrl.monthsForm.institution);">
    <option value=""  selected>Select a Bank
</select>
```

I am checking condition over here

```
function getPerfiosData() {

    var tribeId = vm.currentTribeId;

    getPerfiosAnalysisData(tribeId).then(function(response) {
        vm.perfiosAnalysisData = response.data;
        /* Check Select Option Length */
        $scope.lengthData = vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions.length;
        console.log(vm.perfiosAnalysisData);
        console.log(vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0].id);
        console.log(vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0].institution.institution_id);
        if ($scope.lengthData === 1) {

            vm.setCurrNeftInsti(vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0].institution.institution_id, 'abbanalysis');



        }
        /* Check Select Option Length */
        vm.isPerfiosEnabled = response.is_enabled;
        setChartDataConfig();
        getDrawGraph();
    }, function(err) {
        if (err.status === 412) {
            vm.perfiosNotPermitted = true;
        }
    });
}
```

I can call ng-change function but option value i can't able to call how i achive this

Comment: You want to select the first option in dropdown if it has single option?

Comment: Yes correct ....

Comment: Where are you calling `getPerfiosData` method ? and post the sample data that is returned by `response.data`

Comment: i load this getPerfiosData init function response.data this just declare only

Comment: How are you referring your controller in HTML and Where is `getPerfiosData` method defined? Would you mind to add the source code?

Comment: i am using viewProfileCtrl in thml i am binding this viewProfileCtrl

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to select the first option in `dropdown` if it has single option.

You don't need to call the method `setCurrNeftInsti`. Just set the dropdown ng-model as `vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0]` as below

```
function getPerfiosData() {
    var tribeId = vm.currentTribeId;
    getPerfiosAnalysisData(tribeId).then(function(response) {
        vm.perfiosAnalysisData = response.data;
        /* Check Select Option Length */
        $scope.lengthData = vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions.length;
        if ($scope.lengthData === 1) {
            $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
                vm.monthsForm.institution = vm.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions[0];    
            });
        }
        /* Check Select Option Length */
        vm.isPerfiosEnabled = response.is_enabled;
        setChartDataConfig();
        getDrawGraph();
    }, function(err) {
        if (err.status === 412) {
            vm.perfiosNotPermitted = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i already try this i got this error Cannot set property 'institution' of undefined